# Zend Framework and UTF-8 characters (æøå)

Tags: zend-framework

I use Zend Framework and I have problem with JSON and UTF-8.

**Output**

```
\u00c3\u00ad\u00c4\u008d
Ã­Ä
```

I use...

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

- `contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",`
- `dataType : "json"`

**Zend Framework**

- `$view->setEncoding('UTF-8');`
- `$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');`
- `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`
- `utf8_encode();`
- `Zend_Json::encode`

**Database**

- `resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"`
- `resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"`
- `resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true`

Collation

`utf8_unicode_ci`

Type

`MyISAM`

**Server**

- PHP Version 5.2.6

**What did I do wrong? Thank you for your reply!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> utf8_encode();

If you've got UTF-8 strings from your database and UTF-8 strings from your browser, then you don't need to `utf8_encode` any more. You've already got UTF-8 strings; calling this function again will just give you the UTF-8 representation of what you'd get if you read UTF-8 bytes as ISO-8859-1 by mistake.

Pass your untouched UTF-8 strings straight to the JSON encoder.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602906/how-to-convert-utf-8-text-into-json-format) is some how related to yours 
my problem was when encoding some [ Arabic , Hebrew   or Chinese  as you might see ] 
turns out that unicode notation understood by javascript/ecmascript like what did you see

I hope that explain to you in details